# Django 1.4 dependency when packaging a Precise application

Tags: packaging, django

I am trying to package a program I wrote that depends on Django 1.4.1 in Ubuntu 12.04.  As Django 1.4.1 isn't available in Precise I am wondering if it is best to:

Package up Django 1.4.1 and drop it in my ppa

OR

write a script that wgets Django at build time and installs.

OR

Something better that I haven't thought of.

I am still inexperienced with packaging and would appreciate some advice

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution is putting a notice on your PPA description for users to manually install newer version, e.g. "install Django 1.4.1 via this PPA first: [...]". However, I can't seem to find any semi-official PPA providing this latest release of Django.

For Quantal (12.10), `1.4.1` is already included in the main repositories ([`python-django` in Quantal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/python-django)). So, try to re-build the regular Ubuntu package for Precise and put it in your PPA. That seems to be the easiest and best way in your case, I think. More people can profit from your work of backporting this Django version for Precise! It also allows you to set a clear dependency on your package.

I would avoid any scripts downloading and installing packages from source, unless licensing issues are forcing you this way - e.g. Adobe Flash, Oracle Java, MS fonts, etc.